# Getting all instances of a specific type within a class

Tags: python, class

Is there a way to get a list or return all the instances of a class within a class in python? I've already done some research into it and all the answers that I've seen assume the instances are global variables, not part of an existing class.

For example, can I find all instances of `Bar` that are instantiated within the class `Foo` below?

```
class Foo:
   def __init__(self):
      self.mymsg1 = Bar('John Doe')
      self.mymsg2 = Bar('Jane Doe')
      self.somenumber = 42
      self.somewords = 'hello world'

class Bar:
   def __init__(self, name):
      self.hellomsg = 'hello ' + name
```

I want to be able to get `mymsg1` and `mymsg2` because they are `Bar` objects, but I don't want any of the other attributes or methods.

Comment: To be clear: You want to find all *attributes* of an *instance of* the class, that happen to have a particular type? What *problem do you hope to solve* by doing this?

Comment: I want to find all the instances of the class Bar which are attributes of the class Foo. The general problem I am solving is the ability to allow users of a program that I'm writing to be able to define a custom parameter via a class (Bar in my example) while within a class (Foo) that they are customizing based on their use case of my program. My program needs to automatically detect those custom paramters in order for my program to work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use class variable very easily:

```
class Foo:
   def __init__(self):
      self.mymsg1 = Bar('John Doe')
      self.mymsg2 = Bar('Jane Doe')
      self.somenumber = 42
      self.somewords = 'hello world'

class Bar:
   _instances = []
   def __init__(self, name):
      Bar._instances.append(self)
      self.hellomsg = 'hello ' + name

>>> f = Foo()
>>> print('first:', Bar._instances[0].hellomsg,
...       ', second:' ,Bar._instances[1].hellomsg)                                                          
first: hello John Doe , second: hello Jane Doe
```

For partitioning the Bar instances by instantiator, one can do this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class Foo:
   def __init__(self):
      self.mymsg1 = Bar('John Doe', self)
      self.mymsg2 = Bar('Jane Doe', self)
      self.somenumber = 42
      self.somewords = 'hello world'

class Bar:
   _instances = defaultdict(list)
   def __init__(self, name, instantiator):
      Bar._instances[instantiator].append(self)
      self.hellomsg = 'hello ' + name

>>> f, ff = Foo(), Foo()
>>> print('first:', Bar._instances[f][0].hellomsg,
...       ', second:' ,Bar._instances[ff][1].hellomsg)                                                          
first: hello John Doe , second: hello Jane Doe
```

Comment: hm interesting! I didn't think of that. and I think it'll work for my application! :) Buuuut I don't think it'll work quite as expected if you had multiple instances of Foo right? if you had `f = Foo()` and `a = Foo()` then the number of instances would now be 4, when I would think the expectation would be for two for each `f` and `a`.

Comment: @theChef613 Nice question, You have to pass the instances of f then, I can modify it to rectify such cases.

Comment: hm, not quite understanding what you mean by "passing the instances of f" sorry :( would love to see a modified answer! In my application, I'd rather add code to the Bar class like you shown anyways so if it can work in the general case then I'd be happy to mark you as the best answer :)

Comment: @theChef613 modified it, I try to come up with a better solution that doesn't require you passing a key to Bar in the time of instantiation for book keeping.

Comment: woah! really cool.. I actually did not know you can pass self in the same line as the instantiation of self like you did. I'd be interested to see if you do happen to come up with something "neater". thanks man!

Comment: Note that this relies upon the fact that subclasses of `object` have a default `__hash__` with per-instance uniqueness property. This may not work as expected with classes that override `__hash__` themselves.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and most effective method is to create an appropriate data structure and avoid doing Python magic. However, if you have a degree in serpentine magic, I have listed various methods of advanced wizardry below.

### Search `__dict__`

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar1 = Bar()
        self.bar2 = Bar()

    def bars(self):
        return [v for v in self.__dict__.values() if isinstance(v, Bar)]
```

### Manually register each name

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self._bar_names = {"bar1", "bar2"}
        self.bar1 = Bar()
        self.bar2 = Bar()

    def bars(self):
        return [self.__dict__[x] for x in self._bar_names]
```

### Automatically register names by overriding `__setattr__`

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self._bar_names = set()
        self.bar1 = Bar()
        self.bar2 = Bar()

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name == "_bar_names":
            self.__dict__[name] = value
            return
        if isinstance(value, Bar):
            self._bar_names.add(name)
        else:
            self._bar_names.discard(name)
        self.__dict__[name] = value

    def bars(self):
        return [self.__dict__[x] for x in self._bar_names]
```

Comment: yeah I agree it's best to work around these kinds of things.. :/ but I didn't really see another way to work this. I think your first answer is the simplest and most to the point of the three, but could. and it has the advantage of being part of the `Foo` class which means that each instance of `Foo` would have its own count of `Bar`.

Answer (score 1):

This way you could filter whatever the class you pass by argument, and the function returns an array of that class objects.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
      self.mymsg1 = Bar('John Doe')
      self.mymsg2 = Bar('Jane Doe')
      self.somenumber = 42
      self.somewords = 'hello world'
      
    def filter_class(self, _class):
      return [i[1] for i in (self.__dict__).items() if isinstance(i[1],_class)]
      
  class Bar:
     def __init__(self, name):
        self.hellomsg = 'hello ' + name
```